# PHP MVC - Calling view functions from model, or controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

After reading a fair few posts on Stack, and also some material recommended to me on line, the MVC pattern is quite open to interpretation, so please don't answer with another explanation. Thanks!

I'm reaching the end of designing my own PHP MVC now, and have two possible ways to move forward with the views.

But first, my controllers are currently quite dumb, not containing any classes and simply call public methods from the suitable models, and render the appropriate view.

Views are included as necessary, so naturally the objects are available to them via the constructors, along with all the methods (inc delete/update etc).

My first option is to get data using something like this in the view

```
foreach($object->fetchData() as $data)
```

and then looping through the results. However some people do not agree with this, and have suggested that such methods should be excluded from the view. Instead it has been recommended that I assign this to a variable in the constructor, and then use this variable in the view

```
//constructor
$fetched_data = $object->fetchData()

// view
foreach($featched_data as $data)
```

I don't like this very much, as it seams messy and unnecessary.

With all my critical methods being made available to the view, could this be considered a problem?

So here's the question. Do I keep it how it is, and create new methods in the MODEL for rendering data (as above) OR can I create a class in the constructor, extend the model into it, protect the critical functions in the model, and then create my read only public methods in the CONSTRCUTOR?

Thanks!

Comment: Voting to migrate to [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), since it's about software design concepts rather than solving a specific coding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class in the constructor. Not only would extending the model be a much safer approach, but it'd also minimize the calling of functions in the views. Am assuming you'll have several views, it's much easier to get access the constructor data than calling method functions each time in each view.

You can add classes to your controllers that will call the method functions and pass the data directly into the views, instead of clustering your constructor or bootstrap.